# What image processing does WordPress use?

Tags: php, adobe-photoshop, wordpress

I'm having a problem that I haven't had before. I'm saving these images out as sRGB Everything is great on screen, even look okay on the site when it displays the full resolution but, during thumbnail creation it's ruining red. Absolutely destroying the image. (all images are the same monitor... and they're screenshots so it doesn't matter. Just don't suggest that.)

This one is the thumbnail on WP, next to the same image in Photoshop.

[image: thumbnail on WP, next to same image in Photoshop.]

This one is the metadata in Bridge

[image: metadata in Bridge]

Photoshop color profile settings

[image: color profile settings]

And thumbnails from an FTP download from about an hour ago, from an upload Monday.

[image: thumbnails from an FTP download]

All with no extreme plugins

[image: no extreme plugins]

Comment: Does the problem appear in multiple browsers on multiple machines? What happens if you save the image with no ICC profile embedded (again check multiple browsers on multiple machines)?

Comment: Look at this two pages, that are related to your question: [1](https://kb.oboxthemes.com/articles/wordpress-uploaded-images-lose-quality-or-look-pixelly/) - [2](https://www.proteusthemes.com/blog/ultimate-guide-image-optimization-wordpress/#the-contents-of-this-article-in-3-min-video). In Photoshop remember to use File > Save for Web, when saving images for the Web.

Comment: I hate using that though, Spike. Would rather it be more actionable and was hoping to figure it out without that.

No ICC profiles @cybernetic. Thanks Buddy

Answer (score 0):

Show me the "Assign to Profile" dialog box under Edit/Assign to Profile

You'll also have to provide details on the format you're using to publish the files and the attributes you're using.